# Get wrong data by pointer assignment to String::utf8().data() in webcore

Tags: string, webkit, variable-assignment

A function of a **webkit** plugin which has a ***String*** type parameter as below interface
    `int handleString(String str);`

I wrote the code in the function as below
   `const char *data = str.utf8().data();`
And try to print the data as below.
  `printf("data = %s\n", data);`
Also do below
  `printf("str = %s\n", str.utf8().data());`

But, I saw different in the 2 print. data points to a string which the first few bytes were modified.

Could anybody tell me why? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To print using printf its safe to use str.ascii().data().

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue.
Not sure why the first 8 digits are jumbled.

No matter what u pass only the 1st 8 char are lost. Rest string appears to be as normal.

Was able to resolve the issue by using STRDUP api